# Parent and 2 degree inner fragments communication

Tags: android, android-fragments, search

I have the following structure in a fragment.

[image: Structure]

I have also this code to change fragments.

```
   search_box.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            changeFragment(new SearchAFragment());
        }
    });

    search_box.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            changeFragment(new SearchBFragment());
            return false;
        }
    });
```

As you see, according to search view state, fragments changes. When searchview is not focused, an empty fragment is shown in the framelayout (shape 1). After enabling searchview, a viewpager vith tabs shown in the framelayout (shape 2). I need to use searchview's onTextChangedListener in viewpager's fragments.

I am using them like this;

```
((android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) getParentFragment().getView().findViewById(R.id.search_box)).setOnQueryTextListener(new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I put the above code to both fragments that are in the viewpager and it works only for second fragment in the viewpager. I guess the listener in the second fragment overrides the first one in the first fragment of viewpager.

So as a result, in the fragments of viewpager, the operation of filling recycler view is done and the text is put into search view in the outer fragment in the shape 1. How can I handle this listening issue?

Comment: One thing you can do as solution is take `pageChangeListener` for `ViewPager` where your viewpager is (might be in middle fragment), and during **page selected method** call public method of your viewpager fragments and inside of it, set your *listener of searchview*. In such a way you'll get notified on particular fragment.

Comment: This did not help but I tried to use setVisibleHint in the viewpager's fragments but this time in setVisibleHint() getParentFragment returns null.